# Bootstrap Navbar center brand with responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing Bootstrap nav bar logo in order that it'll be at the centre. Recently, I found css code to solve. However, the point is that it's perfect with the large devices, but when I used the inspect element with a small device, it's not responsive as I thought. 
This is the code:

```css
.sFont{
  font-family: Gotham-Med; 
  color: #ffffff; font-size: 25pt; 
  text-align: center;
}
.centeR {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: black; border: none; border-radius: 0px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">  
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="centeR sFont"><img  style="height: 45px;" src="Logo.png"/>&nbsp;Penston</p>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[This is perfect as I wanted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah8WQ.png)

[The text's overlapping with icon bar which I can't even click on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4wRD.png)

Can you suggest me? I tried to do it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. You can position the image absolutely, then the text relative to the image and offset it with negative margin across the `navbar` so everything is centered.

See example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand img {
  margin-top: -15px;
  height: 50px;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .logo {
  margin-top: -35px;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  font-family: Gotham-Med;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse > .container .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered,
.navbar.navbar-inverse > .container-fluid .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  margin-left: -110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        <p class="logo">Penston</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're welcome and glad I was able to help. If the solution worked, please mark your question as answered so others can benefit from it.